# Amazon Linux 2 Crontab not working Properly

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to Execute a script though crontab : At every minute on every day-of-month from 1 through 5 and every day-of-month from 16 through 23 and on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.
So my expression is `* * 1-5,16-23 * 1-5`.
Today is 14th of the Month and I can see it's still triggered my Script through Crontab.

I assume script being triggered either date is matched or Monday to Friday.
Can Anyone help me with this cron expression.

Comment: I hope crontab(5) helps:
`For example, "30 4 1,15 * 5" would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every  Friday. One can, however, achieve the desired result by adding a test to the command (see the last example in EXAMPLE CRON FILE below)` and the last example is `0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"` (Run on every second Saturday of the month)

Comment: @yvs2014 I am still little confuse, what cron expression do I need to run for the above scenario.

Comment: there is not totaly clear from the question, which combinatiion day-of-month day-of-week you want to get

Comment: If I got it correctly `* * 1-5 * * cmd` fits your first condition (from 1th to 5th day of month), and `* * 16-23 * * sh -c 'd=$(date +\%u); test "$d" -ge 1 -a "$d" -le 5 && cmd'` for the second part (from 16th to 23th day of month, but only if it's not a weekend)